# Magento - get Customer Address id of order shipping address

Tags: magento, checkout, addressbook, billing

I got the shipping address of an order by $order->getShippingAddress()

```
$order = Mage::getModel('Mage_Sales_Model_Order');
$order->loadByIncrementId($ext_order_id);
$address = $order->getShippingAddress();
```

and i load the DefaultBillingAddress by

```
$address_default_billing = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()
                                    ->getDefaultBillingAddress();
```

Now i want to compare them, but there's the problem. If i do a `getId()` on both of them, they have different id's even though i chose the billing address for shipping in checkout, so they have to be the same but the id is different.. how can that appear ? Is there a way to get the customer-address-id of the current shippingaddress in checkout ?

by example: `$address->getId()` returns 44 and `$address_default_billing->getId()` return 6

the 6 is the right id for the customer address in the model, but the order-shipping-id is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get customer address by `customer_address_id` field in `sales_flat_order_address` table

here the code:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$order->loadByIncrementId($ext_order_id);
$address = $order->getShippingAddress();
$address->getData('customer_address_id');
```

Comment: Thank u. Helps a lot and it works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The address `id` will never be the same, because after an order is placed the address info will 'never' change while customer address change as customer move or change there shipping address.

Order address is store in `sales_flat_order_address`

Customer address is store in `customer_address_entity*`

To compare the address you want want to compare individual elements

```
$address_data = $address->getData()
$address_default_billing_data = $address_default_billing->getData()

$compare = array('firstname', ..., 'city');

foreach($compare as $c){
   if($address_data[$c] != $address_default_billing_data[$c]){
     //not equal
     break;
   }

}
```